# How to simplify the expression $(\log_9 2 + \log_9 4)\log_2 (3)$

Tags: logarithms

Our test asked to simplify $(\log_9 2 + \log_9 4)\log_2 (3)$.

I simplified the first parenthesis to be $\log_9 (8)$.

So, now I have $\log_9 (8) \cdot \log_2 (3)$ and I can change to base $10$ and get, $$\frac{\log 8}{\log 9} \cdot \frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$$ However, the problem shows that this should without a calculator simplify to $1.5$.  Without using a calculator, I don't see how I'm supposed to get $3/2$ from the multiplication of these $2$ logs.  Any thoughts?

Comment: $\log(9) = 2 \log(3)$ and $\log(8) = 3 \log(2)$

Comment: Thank you sooooo much.  I see it now, but not sure I would have seen it on the test.

Answer (score 3):

$$(\log_{9}2+\log_9{4})\log_{2}3$$
this equal to:
$$\log_{9}8\cdot \log_{2}3=\frac{3\log2}{2\log3}\cdot\frac{\log3}{\log2}=\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**  $\log_{10} 8 = \log_{10} 2^3 = 3\log_{10} 2$ and $\log_{10} 9 = \log_{10} 3^2 = 2\log_{10} 3$.

Comment: Yes, I see now.  Thank you for taking the time!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** It's a bit confusing with your notation, but you can use the fact that

$$
\log_9 8 \times \log_2 3 = \log_9 8^{\log_2 3}
$$

and observe that

$$
8 = 2^3
$$

It will also be useful to know that (in this context)

$$
(a^b)^c = (a^c)^b
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\log_{9}2+\log_9{4})\log_{2}3$$
$$=(\log_{9}2+\log_9{2^2})\log_{2}3$$
$$=(\log_{9}2+2*\log_9{2})\log_{2}3$$
$$=(3*\log_9{2})*\log_{2}3$$
$$=3*\log_9{2}*\log_{2}3$$
$$=3*\log_9{3}$$
$$=3*\log_9{9^{1/2}}$$
$$={3/2}*\log_9{9}$$
$$={3/2}$$